# How to get the Max of Total in JPA?

Tags: jpa

Hi I have to write JPQL command that does something specific the question is exactly:

"Find those students that has the greatest total of studypoint scores?"

There are just two Entity classes that looks like :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findById", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findByFirstname", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.firstname = :firstname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findByLastname", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.lastname = :lastname")})
public class Student implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "studentId", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Studypoint> studypointCollection;

     public void addStudyPoint(Studypoint cc) {
        if (studypointCollection == null) {
            studypointCollection = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        studypointCollection.add(cc);
        cc.setStudentId(this);
    }
```

and the other class

```
        @Entity
@Table(name = "studypoint")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Studypoint.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Studypoint s"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Studypoint.findById", query = "SELECT s FROM Studypoint s WHERE s.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Studypoint.findByDescription", query = "SELECT s FROM Studypoint s WHERE s.description = :description"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Studypoint.findByMaxval", query = "SELECT s FROM Studypoint s WHERE s.maxval = :maxval"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Studypoint.findByScore", query = "SELECT s FROM Studypoint s WHERE s.score = :score")})
public class Studypoint implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "MAXVAL")
    private Integer maxval;
    @Column(name = "SCORE")
    private Integer score;
    @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne
    private Student studentId;
```

As you can see Student can have many Studypoints. Which I really struggle is this JPQl: Please help.

Comment: "Which I really struggle in this..." & what is this referring to. Did you tried first constructing plain SQL with join, grouping etc. & then converting to JPQL.

Answer (score 0):

I tried for sometime to get this working with JQL and I can't see how you wrap the max in the sum, so I switched to SQL.

It's not ideal, but here is my repository:

```
package net.isban.fmis.repository;

import net.isban.fmis.entity.Studypoint;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface StudyPointRepository extends CrudRepository<Studypoint, Integer> {

    @Query(value="select top 1 id from (select sum(score) scoresum, student.id from studypoint join student on student.id=studypoint.student_id group by student.id) order by scoresum desc", nativeQuery=true)
    Integer findStudentIdWithMaxScore();

}
```